# Did Jesus' listeners understand which father he was talking about?

Tags: jesus

> For whosoever shall do the will of my Father which is in heaven, the same is my brother, and sister, and mother. Mattews 12:50 KJV

Did Jesus' listeners understand which father he was talking about?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, Jesus' listeners did understand the identity of the "Father" to whom Jesus referred.

> <sup>17</sup> But Jesus answered them, My Father worketh hitherto, and
> I work.
> <sup>18</sup> Therefore the Jews sought the more to kill him, because he not only
> had broken the sabbath, but said also that God was his Father, making
> himself equal with God.  (John 5:17-18, KJV)

This incident was in relationship to the healing of the paralytic, and the Jews had questioned the man about who had healed him, then they questioned Jesus about why he had done this on the Sabbath.  When Jesus spoke of his Father, his words conveyed their intended meaning, and his listeners understood what he was really saying.  The context had made this clear.